# How to Expose DocumentDB Attachments over Http?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are storing image into documentdb. Is it possible to expose images as public HTTP endpoint?

Something similar to BLOB: where we could configure the container as public & send fully qualified image URL to the browser for rendering.

**EDIT:**

Being impressed by DocDB attachments we started evaluating that option to store images, however it seems there is no benefit of using attachments rather more overheads of dealing with `MediaLink` & `SelfLink` & additional calls to Database for fetching attachments.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same question when we were using it in one of our application. Simple answer is that right now you can't. What you would have to do is read the attachment contents in your application and stream it from there.

Comment: Happy Weekends Gaurav :-) In one of my project I need to return three images, as response from controller. I do not think it would be best to return bytes & render them as Base64 string in the browser. This limitation suggests that I should still stick to BLOB for storing images etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how fair it is to expect a document Type No-SQL database engine to store binary files. What is the use case? On our end, usually we store direct blob links in DocDB and let the client application fetch the binary itself from the blob.

Comment: I would agree with @daronyondem and use blob storage to store the files and store the links in DocumentDB document.

Comment: why the hack you both want to store images in a Database ?! And no, it is not easier to make backup of whole application data, it is lazier!

Comment: @daronyondem We are making CMS application leveraging NoSQL. The goal is application should work on mobile devices even when it is not connected to internet

Comment: @daronyondem Being impressed by DocDB attachments we started evaluating that option to store images, however it seems there is no benefit of using attachments rather more overhaeads of dealing with `MediaLink` & `SelfLink`

Comment: Abhijeet --> Given that DocumentDB is a service hosted in Azure and you would need Internet connectivity to connect to the service, I'm not sure how your comment above about offline capability is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Gaurav, exposing an http endpoint for attachments is not currently supported. If this is important for you, you can store the attachments in docdb as metadata only (see "Sample Request: Attachment without Raw Media (only metadata)" [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn803933.aspx)). Your link to the actual attachment (which you will provide to docdb in the metadata) should be a blob storage service URI that clients can connect to directly (such as using Azure Blob Storage  with public container/blobs or with Shared Access Signatures).